# How to print data from an array php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having some troubles calling the correct values in the php array. Here is the array.

`Array ( [count] => 1 [threads] => Array ( [13] => Array ( [thread_id] => 13 [node_id] => 4 [title] => Forum Integration nearly complete! [reply_count] => 0 [view_count] => 0 [user_id] => 59 [username] => Faeron [post_date] => 1369257302 [sticky] => 0 [discussion_state] => visible [discussion_open] => 1 [discussion_type] => [first_post_id] => 23 [first_post_likes] => 0 [last_post_date] => 1369257302 [last_post_id] => 23 [last_post_user_id] => 59 [last_post_username] => Faeron [prefix_id] => 1 [content] => Array ( [count] => 1 [content] => Array ( [23] => Array ( [post_id] => 23 [thread_id] => 13 [user_id] => 59 [username] => Faeron [post_date] => 1369257302 [message] => It's been quite a while since we began to integrate the phanime Forums with the main site. We have now finished the integration with the phanime Forums and the main site. You will no longer notice that there are two platforms running phanime, but instead only one. Our next step is to theme the forums to make it look like the main site! [ip_id] => 268 [message_state] => visible [attach_count] => 0 [position] => 0 [likes] => 0 [like_users] => a:0:{} [warning_id] => 0 [warning_message] => ) ) ) ) ) )`

Now lets say this array was named `$array` then to get the first element's value "[count]" can't I just say the following: `print $array["[count]"]`  <-- this returns an error.

What about the element that has a value as an array itself, which is the `[threads]` element. How do I get, perhaps the `[thread_id]` element's value?

Comment: Is this really what you're code looks like?  How can you possibly follow it?

Comment: the array, is returned from "print_r($array)" so I can see the whole array. 

I just need to figure out how I can get values of one element of the array... I've looked at the syntax, and I can't find an example where they use "[blah] => value" ... instead they use "element" => "value". I just need to figure out how to call these elements in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
echo $array['count']; // would output '1'
echo $array['threads'][13]['thread_id']; // outputs '13'
echo $array['threads'][13]['content']['content'][23]['message']; // "It's been.."
```

Here is the (brief) documentation on multidimensional arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Here's a good guide to them with examples: http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/01/php-arrays-array-functions-and-multidimensional-arrays/

**Update:** To get the value of 'message' without knowing the numbered array keys beforehand you could use:

```
reset($array);
$first = array_keys($array['threads']);
$first = $first[0];
$second = array_keys($array['threads'][$first]['content']['content']);
$second = $second[0];
echo $array['threads'][$first]['content']['content'][$second]['message'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply, this is great. I was able to get the variables. I have a question, what if I don't know the name of the array that is inside another, how can I simply get the first array found inside another array without knowing it's name? Is it possible? If so, how? The array ['13'] and the array ['23'] in the example, I have no way of knowing their names, how can I refer to them?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a value in an array by using the following:

```
echo $array['count'];
```

You can also print the entire array like so:

```
print_r($array);
```

or

```
var_dump($array);
```

If you want to write a value from a multidimensional array then use the following:

```
echo $array[23]['post_id'];
```

So, to summarize, see the following:

```
$array = array(
    'bar'  => 'testing value',
    'foo'  => array(
         'bar' => 'test'
    )
);

print_r($array) // Will print whole array
echo $array['bar']; // Will print 'testing value'
print_r($array['foo']); // Will print the second level array
echo $array['foo']['bar']; // Will print 'test'
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply, this is great. 

I was able to get the variables. I have a question, what if I don't know the name of the array that is inside another, how can I simply get the first array found inside another array without knowing it's name? Is it possible? If so, how?